# Bug in system information script 'inxi' - displaying folder content instead of info

Tags: debugging

I just ran `inxi -m` (version `2.2.16-0ubuntu1` on Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit), which should...

```
-M   Show machine data. Motherboard, Bios, and if present, System Builder (Like Lenovo).  Older systems/kernels without
     the  required /sys data can use dmidecode instead, run as root. If using dmidecode, may also show bios revision as
     well as version. -! 33 can force use of dmidecode data instead of /sys.
```

<sup>(excerpt from `man inxi`)</sup>

...but in my case, it filled the result mask with file names from my home directory!

```
$ inxi -M
Machine:   System: MAXDATA product: Desktop v: Documents serial: Downloads
           Mobo: Pictures model: Public v: PythonProjects serial: Templates
           Bios: Videos v: bin rv ASUSTeK date: iconlist.txt
```

**Can I apply any patch or workaround myself to fix it?**

Comment: What happens when you run `ubuntu-bug inxi`?

Comment: So do you want the answer to contain a patch and instructions on how to apply it or just instructions on how to apply patches in general?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda An answer specific to *this* problem, of course!

Comment: So do you expect me to make the patch and show you how to apply it or find a workaround or something and explain it? Or do you just want to know if there is already a patch or workaround out there? I mean, if there is no patch or workaround yet out there, would my answer in its current state be acceptable or do you want me to come up with the patch/workaround?

Comment: @ByteCommander the Google Code page says the project and issue tracker have moved to Github: https://github.com/smxi/inxi

Comment: @muru Thanks, I ran `ubuntu-bug inxi` now and the bug report linked in my answer below was created.

Comment: @ByteCommander for what it's worth, I can't reproduce on 14.04 (running the inxi versions `1.9.17-00` and `2.2.16-00` - downloaded manually) or Arch Linux (`2.2.31-00`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this bug through `ubuntu-bug inxi` on Launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inxi/+bug/1529689).

I also wrote a bug report on GitHub [here](https://github.com/smxi/inxi/issues/75).

---

The author and owner of the GitHub repository - smxi - confirmed and fixed this bug. It always occurs when there is a `*` character anywhere in the fetched system information.

**If this bug affects you too** and your Ubuntu repository package version is still below `2.2.32-00` (compiled before 2016-01-03), you can download the executable script from smxi's server and replace your current version with it using the following command:

```
sudo wget -O /usr/bin/inxi smxi.org/inxi
```

This will replace the executable of your currently installed (e.g. through `apt-get`) `inxi` version with the latest version.

If you had the version from the official Ubuntu repository installed before, this command will *not* mess up anything. The package manager will not notice the change and think it's still the old version. You can later uninstall or upgrade it without problems.

Comment: You might want to run `inxi -@14 -M` and attach the `inxi` log files to the bug report. Or run `bash -x inxi -@7 -M`.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I added the output file to the launchpad bug report.